# Switching the smallest and largest value in an object array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm instructed to swap the largest and smallest value in an object array in Java. I wrote my code and it seems reasonable, but for some reason the values aren't switching??? I'm not quite sure what's wrong with my code, can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you!!

**This is my code:**

```
public class Measurables
{
   /**
      Swaps the values with the smallest and largest measure.
      @param objects an array of objects of a class that implements the
      Measurable interface.
   */
   public static void swapMinAndMax(Measurable[] objects)
   {

      Measurable largest = objects[0]; 
      Measurable smallest = largest;
      for (int i = 1 ; i < objects.length ; i++)
      {
         Measurable current = objects[i];
         if ( largest.getMeasure() < current.getMeasure())
         {
            largest = current;
         }
         if (smallest.getMeasure() < current.getMeasure())
         {
            smallest = current;
         }
         Measurable temp = largest; 
         largest = smallest;
         smallest = temp;

         }
      }
}
```

**This is what I get when I run the tester:**

```
Testers

Running Tester.java

fail
[Uruguay, Thailand, Belgium]
Expected: [Uruguay, Belgium, Thailand]
Running Tester2.java

fail
[BankAccount[balance=1000.0], BankAccount[balance=3000.0], BankAccount[balance=2000.0]]
Expected: [BankAccount[balance=3000.0], BankAccount[balance=1000.0], BankAccount[balance=2000.0]]
Running Tester3.java

pass
[Uruguay]
Expected: [Uruguay]
```

Comment: You don't save your swapped array.
You are testing every value, but you don't return your array sorted the way you want

Comment: To expand on sheplu's comment: there's no need to return the array, you can modify it in place.  But you don't change the items, just your local variables which point to .  I.e. at the end do `objects[largest_index] = smallest; objects[smallest_index] = largest;`.  (You'll need to keep track of these indices too.)

Comment: I think you could use the `sort` method [in the Arrays class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-). Just pass the array and a lambda expression indicating when a value is greater than other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the indices of your elements so you can perform the swap *after* you determine the smallest and largest indices. Also, you seem to have swapped the comparison for smallest. Something like,

```
public static void swapMinAndMax(Measurable[] objects) {
    int largest = 0, smallest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < objects.length; i++) {
        Measurable current = objects[i];
        if (objects[largest].getMeasure() < current.getMeasure()) {
            largest = i;
        }
        if (objects[smallest].getMeasure() > current.getMeasure()) {
            smallest = i;
        }
    }
    // Now swap, we know the indexes.
    Measurable temp = objects[largest];
    objects[largest] = objects[smallest];
    objects[smallest] = temp;
}
```